# Simple-form associations creating empty input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form, rails-activerecord

For some reason my simple_form code is inserting

```
<input name="order[product_ids][]" type="hidden" value="">
```

under the form

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input class="check_boxes optional" id="order_product_ids_11" 
           name="order[product_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="11">Product11
</label>
```

When I use my has_and_belongs_to_many association form

```
<%= f.association :products, as: :check_boxes, include_blank: false %>
```

with model Orders

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_and_belongs_to_many :products
```

and products

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
```

which causes the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in OrdersController#create

Couldn't find all Products with IDs (3, 5, ) (found 2 results, but was looking for 3)


{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"F0c4J81QXRNMFDXrN55XrRafwj86lzUl3kXe/xXxKxc=",
 "order"=>{"order_type"=>"init_purchase",
 "shipping_status"=>"unshipped",
 "product_ids"=>["3",
 "5",
 ""]},
 "commit"=>"Create Order"}
```

because it passes an empty value for one of the products. When i manually remove the empty input field with no value, it does not have an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a SimpleForm's thing but Rails's. There will be a config option for this in Rails 4 but now you have to remove it manually.

You can read a bit about this [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5402)

Comment: Thanks, would never have found this. Although, I'm still confused if the previous func. is a feature or a bug.

Comment: How do you use this `:include_hidden` feature with simple_form to avoid this 'empty id' issue?

Comment: How were folks handling this in Rails 3.2.14 ? Cannot migrate to Rails4 yet.

Comment: What is the name of that config option in Rails 4? Could you provide any hint or link to documentation?